# Change from UIViewController to UITableViewController

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit

This one make me go crazy. I am building an iphone app where the first view is a login view. UIViewController, when the user succesfully logs in i want to display i table view. Somehow i just have big problems doing this.

In my app delegate i load my loginViewController, and then i want from the loginViewController load my listViewController.

What is the logic behind switching to a UITableViewController from a UIViewController?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you'd better to do it in your app delegate and surely NOT add the UITableViewController.view to the UIViewController.view... just add it to the UIWindow and then dismiss the old UIViewController (removeFromSuperView it's view and then release it)

**EDIT:**

that's how i manage:

i add a method in my appDelegate:

```
-(void)switchMainView;
```

and from my UIViewController i just call it with this:

```
[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] switchMainView];
```

in switchMainView i just
 remove my UIViewController.view from superview, 
release UIViewController, 
alloc the UITableViewController and init it, then 
add its view to the window app:

```
-(void)switchMainView{
    if (mainView!=nil){ // mainView is the UIViewController
        [mainView.view removeFromSuperview];
        [mainView release];
        mainView = nil;
    }
    Menu *vc; // Menu is my class, subClass of a UITableViewController
    vc = [[Menu alloc] init];
    nc = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vc];
    [window addSubview:nc.view];
    [vc release];
}
```

and then i do the same for going back, eventually

Comment: So a great way to do this would to register a notification in the app delegate, and then send it when user gets loged in and change view in app delegate again? Or is it possible to run methods in app delegate directly from loginViewController?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you already have your custom UITableViewController created:

```
YourTableViewController *vc = [[UITableViewController alloc] initWithStyle:...];
[self presentModalViewController:vc animated:YES];
[vc release];
```

Comment: I would suggest the other way around opening the loginViewController from your tableviewcontroller. This way you can check if the user is already logged in the viewDidLoad and if not display the loginViewController via presentModalViewController. You could create a protocol and implement it on the tableViewController that the loginViewController call a method to let the tableviewcontroller know that the user is logged in.

Answer (score 0):

you can use either i do'nt think there is a major impact but definitely they might have some advantage/Disadvantage over other..

for better understanding read the below tutorial.

http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/03/recreating-uitableviewcontroller-to.html